# Counting the rows of a list where the order of numbers in the row doesn't matter

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

I am trying to make a computation with a large set of rows. As a sample, suppose I have a list of numbers with rows and columns like such:

```
A =
4   1   3   1   3
2   3   2   4   1
2   2   4   3   2
3   2   4   3   2
1   2   4   2   3
4   1   3   2   2
2   2   2   1   2
2   1   2   4   3
1   3   2   1   1
3   4   3   3   4
3   1   4   2   2
```

In Mathematica code this would look like

```
A = {{4, 1, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 2, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 2, 4, 3, 2},
     {1, 2, 4, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 4, 3},
     {1, 3, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 4, 3, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2, 2}}
```

I would like to create a tally or find the most common row of numbers with the same number of numbers.

Particularly, the order of numbers does not matter. So for example,
`4 1 3 1 3`,`3 4 1 3 1`,`1 1 3 3 4` and any combination of these numbers or set of unordered numbers are all equivalent. I am trying to count how many rows have the number 3 occur 2 times, the number 1 occur 2 times, and the number 4 occur 1 time. In the list `A` it appears that this unordered set only occurs once.

Furthermore, the unordered set `3   1   4   2   2` occurs 5 times (If a counted correctly).

I would like to create a tally from the initial list `A` which will have the size of `n x 5`

Any pointers, guidance, or suggestions is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please include your list in *Mathematica* code so that it easy to copy and paste. As it is, we can't tell where one row ends and another begins. Anyway look up Tally.

Comment: I am familiar with the call `Tally`, but I don't know how to incorporate it given this situation of unordered sets.

Comment: `CountsBy[A, Sort]`? But this - " I am trying to count how many rows have the number 3 occur 2 times, the number 1 occur 2 times, and the number 4 occur 1 time" is something different, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that your list of lists looks something like

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {10, 5}]
(* {{2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 1, 2},
    {3, 1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3, 3},
    {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Then, we can `Tally` using a `SameTest` that doesn't care about order:

```
Tally[lst, Sort[#1] === Sort[#2] &]
(* {{{2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, 1},
    {{1, 1, 3, 1, 2}, 4}, {{3, 1, 1, 2, 2}, 1},
    {{1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 1}, {{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, 1}, {{3, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 1}} *)
```

Alternatively, `Sort` the elements first:

```
Tally[Sort /@ lst]
(* {{{1, 1, 2, 2, 2}, 1}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, 1},
    {{1, 1, 1, 2, 3}, 4}, {{1, 1, 2, 2, 3}, 1},
    {{1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 1}, {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2}, 1}, {{1, 2, 3, 3, 3}, 1}} *)
```

Or, use `GroupBy` and make an `Association` (as pointed out by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) in a comment do the OP, this can be done more succinctly using `CountsBy`):

```
assoc = Length /@ GroupBy[lst, Sort]
(* <|{1, 1, 2, 2, 2} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2} -> 1,
     {1, 1, 1, 2, 3} -> 4, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3} -> 1,
     {1, 2, 2, 3, 3} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 2, 2} -> 1, {1, 2, 3, 3, 3} -> 1|>
```

What's nice about this is that you can then call the `Association` with various inputs and spit out the number:

```
assoc[{1, 1, 1, 2, 3}]
assoc[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]
(* 4 *)
(* Missing["KeyAbsent", {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}] *)
```

Comment: Any thoughts on performance of different methods? for big lists...

Comment: Thank you, March and @Kuba. I can't wait to know as much as you all.